# How do I open a port on gcloud instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a GCE instance that's spin up using terraform configuration. The instance spins up fine and I can SSH to it. I have a firewall rule to access TCP port 9090:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
NAME                    NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW                         
DENY
allow-http              default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:8080
default-allow-icmp      default  INGRESS    65534     icmp
default-allow-internal  default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:0-65535,udp:0-65535,icmp
default-allow-rdp       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:3389
default-allow-ssh       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:22
fitnesse                default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:9090
```

But I cannot access any server running on port 9090 from the outside.

```
$ curl http://a.b.c.d:9090
curl: (7) Failed to connect to a.b.c.d port 9090: Connection refused
```

I have tried removing all tags on both the instance and the rule to no avail. I created another rule for another port (8080) and it is also unaccessible.

I checked `iptables -L -nv` on the instance and I have this `INPUT` chain rule which seems fine to me:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 163 packets, 26970 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
72510 1208M sshguard   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
```

I though it could come from a docker issue as the service is a docker container with mapped port but it does not work either with a `nc -l 9090`...

**Update:**

I have changed the port mapping from `9090` to `80` and it now works: I can access the server from the outside.

`netstat -lntp` gives me the following:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      864/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1774/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      19537/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::18001                :::*                    LISTEN      12754/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::5778                 :::*                    LISTEN      13837/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::18002                :::*                    LISTEN      12903/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::18003                :::*                    LISTEN      16534/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::18004                :::*                    LISTEN      16546/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1774/sshd
```

This seems to point the issue to an ipv4/ipv6 problem where the docker proxy only binds to ipv6.

I am at a loss, any help on troubleshooting this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: "it does not work either with a nc -l 9090..." seems to be the underlying problem here

Comment: Can you share the output of `sudo netstat -lntp'? This will allow us to check that the service is listening correctly (ie that it is listening on the correct port AND on 0.0.0.0)

Comment: Things are working fine when I open port `80` and remap the docker container with `-p 80:9090`. In other words, the problem seems to appear only for "non-standard" ports. When I force `netcat -l 0.0.0.0 9090` then it also works.

Comment: Couple of years ago I had to configure my hosts with file `/etc/gai.conf` containing `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100`

Comment: What are the targets for this 9090 rule? If it is specific to the tag, make sure your instance does have that particular tag. Or just set "Apply to all" as a target. Look at the "Targets" in Firewall rules console or run 'gcloud compute firewall-rules list --format=json' and check for 'targetTags'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default configuration of Ubuntu since (at least) 16.04 prefers connections through ipv6 rather than ipv4. This is configured in file `/etc/gai.conf` as explained [here](http://terokarvinen.com/2016/prefer-ipv4-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-xenial-etcgai-conf-precedence-ffff0096-100).

This means that processes which do not explicitly choose an address to bind to will by default be bound to any address in the ipv6 namespace, but *not* in the ipv4 address space, which prevents ipv4 connections from outside the box. This can be changed by editing file `/etc/gai.conf` adding the line:

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100
```